# How to compile&run another PDE file in Processing

Tags: java, runtime, processing

I am trying to compile and run another Processing sketch inside one Processing sketch.

I am thinking about using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but I don't know what command to use to compile&run the pde file.

This is my file structure:

[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T88J7.png)

**NMAspaceOS.pde** is my main pde, it is used to execute and terminate other pdes.The **project0, project1, project3** are the Processing projects I am trying to call/run from **NMAspaceOS**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came back to post my solution here.

Because you can actually compile & run PDE file from the command line tool after you have installed "Processing-java", so you can absolutely run another PDE. This 1 line of code does it:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/processing-java --sketch=" + sketchFolderPath + " --run");
```

Just remember to install **processing-java** from **Processsing->Tools**

This works on MacOS, and Linux I presume.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a little tricky, because you're not just compiling `.java` files. You need to first compile the `.pde` file into a `.java` file. Usually you would rely on the Processing editor to do this for you.

The Processing editor is open source, and you can view all of its code [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/app/src/processing/app). You might try digging through that to find the code that converts a `.pde` file into a `.java` file.

But honestly, if I were you I'd take a step back and ask myself if I really needed to do this. Can you refactor your approach so you don't have to do this compilation yourself?